# Equivalent of try-with-resources but throw the exception

Tags: java, try-with-resources

I have a function `read`:

```
public static ArrayList<String> read(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        File fileToRead = path.toFile();
        Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(fileToRead);
        while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
            lines.add(fileReader.nextLine());
        }
        fileReader.close();

        return lines;
    }
```

I want it to pass on a FileNotFoundException if it encounters one, but I'm not sure if encountering this exception while creating the scanner will result in an unclosed scanner.

I'd like to implement a similar behavior that the try-with-resources block provides as shown below, but without catching and re-throwing the error (unless this is the intended solution).

```
public static ArrayList<String> read(Path path) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        File fileToRead = path.toFile();
        
        try (
            Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(fileToRead);
        ) {
            while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
                lines.add(fileReader.nextLine());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw e;
        }

        return lines;
    }
```

Comment: Remove the `catch` block.  "try with resources" is a nicer implementation of `try-finally`, so if you don't `catch` the exception, it will need to be thrown

Comment: oof i assumed this wouldn't compile without it. Thanks :p

Comment: Yeah, I had to test it to ;)

Comment: BTW your `fileReader.hasNext()` should probably be `fileReader.hasNextLine()` since you are reading lines with `fileReader.nextLine()` (unless you want to avoid reading trailing empty lines).